# How and where to correctly add functions in Woocommerce/wordpress; and how to call them?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I am trying to get shopping cart data from a Woo-commerce website using the following code:

```
   $item_name = $cart_item['data']->get_title();
   $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
   $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
```

when I attempt to run the code I get the following errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function WC() in /Users/...
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function WC() in /Users/... on line 6
```

I have added the function I would like to run in the `functions.php` file of my woo-commerce child  theme in  "wp-content" folder. Is this the correct place to add this function?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it will help you...

```
global $woocommerce;
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
   echo $item_name = $cart_item['data']->get_title();
   echo $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
   echo $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you downvote to this answer? You can use this code anywhere you want to show your cart content. Are you clear with the question??